Read ECONNRESET Error only in production for Azure App Service Node App (localhost is fine)
I seem to be having an issue and I'm unsure where to go next to try and solve this.
I have a node/express webapp that relies heavily on external api requests to our partners. When making a request to one specific client's API the authentication and initial requests work, but as soon as I try and upload a file to them I get the read ECONNRESET error on my logs.
When I replicate this locally on my machine I don't get any errors and the files upload properly.
What are some potential reasons on why this would happen only on my deployed azure app service and not locally?
TIA
I've tried updating the node version in my app service, and audited all the npm packages to see if that could be the issue.

If possible, can you share your github repo?

Can you share log stream of your Azure app service ?

Your external API requests in Azure will be originating from a different public IP address to that which it would be when testing locally.
You may also have network security mechanisms in Azure, such as firewalls and network security groups.
You should first verify that you are able to connect to the external API endpoints.

Open the Kudu console for App Service:
In a Web browser, open the URL https://<yourwebapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net
Open Kudu Advanced Tools:
On the left hand side, select Development Tools->Advanced Tools.
Open a PowerShell Session:
Navigate to the Debug Console dropdown and select PowerShell.
Test Connectivity:
Run the following command, substituting hostname with the FQDN of your external API:
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <hostname> -Port 443

This will establish whether there is a connectivity issue between Azure and your external provider. It will return a value of True if it connected successfully, and False if the connection was blocked, either by your Azure network setup, or by your provider.
Some providers operate IP whitelisting. I manage several platforms where this is the case, and requesting a provider to add another IP is often required.
You can use PowerShell in Kudu to identify what public IP address your provider may need with:
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.ipify.org").ip
